Shuffling Coefficients in Euclidean Distance Matrix
Let a real-valued $n\times n$ matrix $A$ that admits a (Euclidean) realization $\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$ in some $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ (i.e. $A$ is a Euclidean distance matrix) and denotes $A_{(i,j)}$ its coefficient on row $i$ and line $j$.
Consider, for any one-to-one map
$$\phi:\{(i,j),1\leq i,j\leq n\}\rightarrow \{(i,j),1\leq i,j\leq n\},$$
the matrix $A^{\phi}$ where $A^{\phi}_{(i,j)}=A_{\phi(i,j)}$, for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$.
Is there any examples where we can find a $\phi$ such that $A^{\phi}$ admits a realization $\{y_{1},...,y_{n}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\{y_{1},...,y_{n}\}$ is not isometric to $\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$ ? Here i mean isometric in the sense that up to reindexing $y_{1},...,y_{n}$, there exists $\Psi$, an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, such that,
$\Psi(x_{i})=y_{i}$, for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

Yes, seaching for homometric sets led me to the following paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669808000322 in which an example is given which also fits your question.
The points $0,1,4,10,12,17 \in \mathbb R$ give distance matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  & 4 & 10 & 12 & 17 \\
1 & 0 & 3 & 9 & 11 & 16 \\
4 & 3 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 13 \\
10 & 9 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 7 \\
12 & 11 & 8 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\
17 & 16 & 13 & 7 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
A permutation of the entries gives
$$
A_{\phi} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  & 8 & 11 & 13 & 17 \\
1 & 0 & 7 & 10 & 12 & 16 \\
8 & 7 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 9 \\
11 & 10 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 6 \\
13 & 12 & 5 & 2 & 0 & 4 \\
17 & 16 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is realized by $0,1,8,11,13,17 \in \mathbb R$. The two sets of points are not related by an isometry.

Oh, it's a great example and a nice paper ! I wasn't aware of the notion of "homometric sets". Thanks a lot.
